# How to make table dynamically multiply column 1 and column 2 and answer in column 3 in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, html-table

what I'm making is a Laravel project. That web page I need to add a table when user insert number in column 1 and column 2 the table should multiply the numbers and should display in column 3.

**Controller code**

```
 public function makeTable(Request $request){        
    $items = $request->get('values');
    $output = '<table class="table table-sm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Item ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Food Item</th>
        <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';

    foreach ($items as $item){            
        $itemId = FoodItem::where('itemName','like','%'.$item.'%')->value('id');          
        $output .= '<tr>
        <th scope="row">'.$itemId.'</th>
        <td>'.$item.'</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</tbody>
    </table>';  

    echo $output;
}
```

What I want is when user input unit price and amount the price should be display automatically by multiplying unit price and amount. 
The user should be able to do this row by row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below does what you would like.

I've add some classes so that it is easier to determine what each `input` and `td` is for.

I've also added the event triggers in a manner that means dynamically added rows will continue to work (click on the add button to see this in action).

**Update** changed the cost per row to an input as requested and added a sum function for the value of all rows.

---

## Demo

```js
// Add event trigger to inputs with class auto-calc
$(document).on("keyup change paste", "td > input.auto-calc", function() {

  // Determine parent row
  row = $(this).closest("tr");

  // Get first and second input values
  first = row.find("td input.unit-price").val();
  second = row.find("td input.amount").val();

  // Print input values to output cell
  row.find(".total-cost").val(first * second);


  // Update total invoice value
  var sum = 0;
  // Cycle through each input with class total-cost
  $("input.total-cost").each(function() {
    // Add value to sum
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });

  // Assign sum to text of #total-invoice
  // Using the id here as there is only one of these
  $("#total-invoice").text(sum);


});


// Add dynamic row to demonstrate works in this case
$(document).on("click", "#add", function() {

  $("tbody").append('<tr><th scope="row">ITEM003</th><td>KNIFE</td><td><input type="text" class="auto-calc unit-price form-control"></td><td><input type="text" class="auto-calc amount form-control"></td><td><input type="text" class="total-cost amount form-control"></td></tr>');
  $(this).remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Food Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">ITEM001</th>
      <td>PLATE</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="auto-calc unit-price form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="auto-calc amount form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="total-cost form-control"></td>
    </tr>
    
    
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">ITEM002</th>
      <td>SPOON</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="auto-calc unit-price form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="auto-calc amount form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="total-cost form-control"></td>
    </tr>
    
    
  </tbody>
</table>


<p>Total invoice amount: <span id="total-invoice">0</span>.
  <p>

    <button id="add">Add row</button>
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Good luck with the rest of your project

Comment: I want to make last column also a input field. How do I do that. <td> <input class="total-cost"></td>  like this. And then I have to change // Print input values to output cell
  row.find("td input.total-cost").text(first * second);  But that doesn't work

Comment: Inputs don't accept .text(), so you need to assign it using .val()

Comment: Finally I need to show the Net price below the table. The how do I get the sum of prices dynamically. Sorry for asking this much. I'm not familiar with Js much.

Comment: Updated for your requests, please accept answer and upvote if it works.

Comment: It works! sorry I can not upvote since my reputation is below 15 :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer but this only works if there is only one row. But in my case it have many rows.

```
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" value="5">
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value=""> <a href="javascript: void(0)" 
onClick="calc()">Calculate</a>

<input type="text" name="output" id="output" value="">
```

And in javascript

```
$("#input2,#input1").keyup(function () {

$('#output').val($('#input1').val() * $('#input2').val());

});
```

This will simply multiply columns.

Comment: The issue you here is using the `id` parameter, it will just find the first example of each. There's no context for the code to recognise that there are multiple rows. This would be a very good way of doing it, if the calculation and inputs only occured once on a page.